# Найти слово и перевернуть его

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Мне надо найти словам, которые удовлетворяют шаблону, и поменять в них порядок слов на обратный. Например, все слова из чётырёх и более букв:

```
import re

s1 = 'she is a rats'
s2 = 'she is a part'
pattern = r'\b(\w){4,}\b'
replace = ? #Вот тут я не знаю как написать

print(re.sub(pattern, replace, s1))
```

Вывод:

```
she is a star
she is a trap
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете передать `lambda`-выражение, которое будет переворачивать слова.

***Пример:***

```py
import re


def main() -> None:
    strings = ['she is a rats', 'she is a part']
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\w){4,}\b')

    for string in strings:
        print(pattern.sub(lambda x: x.group()[::-1], string))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```html
she is a star
she is a trap
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться lambda функцией. Если убрать группу захвата из выражения, функция получит последовательно все найденные совпадения в группу 0

```
import re
pattern = r'\b\w{4,}\b'
replace = lambda x: x.group(0)[::-1]

print(re.sub(pattern, replace, s1))
```